# How can I visually imagine the area of a circle divided by $\pi$?

Tags: circles, pi, area, visualization

If I have a circle with an area of 100 units^2, and I divide it by $\pi$, how can I imagine that visually in my mind?

Since 100 / $\pi$ =~ 31.83, and the square of that is =~ 5.64, I currently visualize the result of 100 / $\pi$ being a box that is 5.64 x 5.64.  And that for whatever reason, 3.14x of those boxes = a circle with a 100 units^2 area.

What is the take away?  That a circle with a certain area can be broken down into 3.14 square boxes of equivalent area?  How can I picture in my mind what that conversion even looks like?

These relationships seem arbitrary and un-useful.  Is there a more meaningful relationship of these two facts?

Also, since this is kind of an open-ended question, is there a better place to ask such questions?

Comment: Why do you want to divide it by π? The usual point is that the _radius_ of the circle is 5.64: That is, if you have a circle with an area of 100 square units, then the distance from the center of the circle to its edge is 5.64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me first answer a slightly different question: how do you visualize that the area of a circle of radius 1 equals $\pi$? The answer I'll give was discovered by the ancients.

Before starting, we have to address what $\pi$ is, and I will take it to equal half the circumference of the radius 1 circle. In other words, I will *define* $$\pi = \text{(circumference)} \, / \, 2 \cdot \text{(radius)}
$$

Imagine cutting the circle up into $1000000$ sectors, using $1000000$ equally spaced radii. Each of those sectors is very, very closely approximated by an isosceles triangle of angle $2 \pi / 1000000$ and of height 1. Number these sectors from $1$ to $1000000$. Lay out sector #1 in the coordinate plane with its base on the $x$-axis (the line $y=0$) and its opposite vertex on the line $y=1$, so it points "upward". Lay out sector #2 with its base on $y=1$ and its opposite vertex on $y=0$, so it points "downward", and so that it shares a side with sector #1. Continuing laying them out, alternating between upward and downward with each one sharing a side with the previous one, until all one million of them are layed out. The area that they fill out is very, very closely approximated by a rectangle whose height equals $1$ and whose base equals half of the circumference which is $\pi$. Therefore the area is very, very close to $\pi$.

So to answer your question directly, repeat this process except starting with a circle $C$ of area $100$. You will end up with a rectangle $R$ such that $$\text{Area of $R$} = \text{Area of $C$}
$$
$$\text{height of $R$} = \text{radius of $C$}
$$
$$
\text{width of $R$} = \text{half the circumference of $C$} = \pi \cdot \text{radius of $C$}
$$
So,
$$\frac{\text{Area}(C)}{\pi} = \frac{\text{Area}(R)}{\pi} = \frac{\text{(height of $R$)} \cdot \text{(width of $R$)}}{\pi} = \frac{\pi(\text{radius of $C$})^2}{\pi} = \text{(radius of $C$)}^2
$$

Comment: It took me 30 minutes to recreate your instructions visually in my head, but it is the most interesting and unusual explanation I have ever encountered.  This will forever be etched inside my head.  Thank you!  Also, during those conversions of sectors to isosceles triangles, about how much of the total area of the circle is lost?

Comment: @user22979: That's an interesting question. I do think it is possible to find upper bounds for the "area error" and to use those upper bounds to demonstrate rigorously that the "area error" goes to zero as the number of subdivisions goes to infinity. But it would take some further work to actually compute those upper bounds...

Comment: @user22979: I'll say briefly how to bound the error. Basically the figure whose area I have computed is the area of the 1000000-sided polygon inside which the circle is inscribed. You can also construct a smaller 1000000-sided polygon outside of which the circle is circumscribed. The area difference between those two polygons is the error bound.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your circle is made of pancake dough, clay or any such thin stretchable material. Take the top point of circle and slightly pinch it in and pull out the points at diagonals until it reaches out to the corner of square. You added some area and removed the same area, you only changed its contour but not its total area...

[circle to square](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1366&bih=617&q=circle%20and%20square&oq=circle%20and%20&gs_l=img.1.1.0l10.1990.5965.0.8965.11.9.0.2.2.0.205.1360.0j8j1.9.0....0...1ac.1.52.img..0.11.1364.RSjxYMKBzI4#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=mazDP6fjmxJnYM%253A%3BABNHUbp533gjQM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fangielskawyspa.pl%252Fuploads%252Fimages%252FAW_obrazki_squaring%252520_0909098.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fangielskawyspa.pl%252Fmatematyka%252F12-circle%3B250%3B250)

Comment: This 'circle to square' concept is interesting, but can you explain how this relates to the area of a circle being divided by π?  This sounds more like how a circle with certain area can be changed into a square of the same area.